# ASP.net MVC seperate solutions with same controller name (different namespace)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some problems when I have same controller name in separate projects.
My main solution is Web forms, and I have two MVC separate projects(separate folder) , the problem If I have a controller in first project with name HomePage and same controller name in solution 2 I have an error:
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'HomePage'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{*pathInfo}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'HomePage' has found the following matching controllers:
Project1.Controllers.HomePageController
Project2.Controllers.HomePageController

The global.asa is in the web forms solution which I added two routes map but I still have same error.
Any solution to fix this issue?
Can I can in the view the action with namespace
@Html.Action("index", "HomePage") 
Thank you

Comment: How are you registering the routes? Show us some code so we can help you, thanks.

Comment: Does one of the MVC projects reference the other? The routing framework merely collects *all* controllers from all available namespaces and then tries to find a matching route. Therefore, it doesn't matter if it's different projects if one references the other.

Comment: Yeah I tried but it take only the first route the second have same error

Comment: no reference between the 2 MVC projects, the project1 have url like www.project1.com and the second is www.project2.com when i add route it work only for the first one

Answer (score 2):

If you need to set the namespaces value when registering the route, you should do so like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "RouteName",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "MyNamespace.Controllers" });
```

By specifying the namespace, it removes the ambiguity.

Comment: I tried to add namespace for both but the problem the application take always the first route

Comment: Can you edit your original post and include the RegisterRoutes code so that we can see where the conflict might be?

Comment: I fixed, the solution is : The second project should have an area , the first one is optional to have it